# Программное закрытие приложения Android

Tags: java, android

Код выставлять не буду, ибо толку от этого ноль в моем случае. Все очень просто. Есть у меня активность авторизации(условно пусть activity1) пользователей с которой стартует приложение. Если пользователь уже авторизован его перекидывает сразу к основной активити приложения(activity3), если нет, то на (activity1) пользователь нажимает регистрация, после чего попадает на activity2 там проходит регистрацию а после попадает на activity3. Проблема в том что по нажатию кнопки back из activity3 я попадаю на activity2 тоесть там где регался(бред получается). Мне нужно сделать так чтобы по нажатию кнопки back из activity3 приложение полностью завершалось.

Answer (score 2):

При открытии activity3 используй флаги:

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Они очистят бэк стек и твоя activity3 будет единственная в стеке. Таким образом при нажатии кнопки Back приложение закроется.

Отличие от `android:noHistory="true"` в том, что если пользователь нажмёт Back при регистрации на activity2, то он перейдёт обратно на авторизацию activity1, как и ожидает. А не просто закроется приложение. Это более логичное поведение навигации.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов как это сделать. Первый не сохранять историю переходов. В этом случае вам нужно в манифесте у activity1 и activity2 добавить:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Второй способ просто переопределить событие onBackPressed и в нем "убить" процесс вашего приложения. Но будьте осторожны с этим. Перед тем как убивать процесс убедитесь что все данные сохранены.

```
public void onBackPressed() { 
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())
}
```

Лично я в своём приложении использую первый способ.